# UWP: Getting the Clipboard Text

Tags: javascript, uwp, clipboard

Here is what I try to get the Clipboards text in js:

```
function getClipboard() {
    var content = Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard.getContent();
    if ( content.contains(Windows.System.string) ) {
        var text = content.getTextAsync(Windows.System.string);
        $('section#show-clipboard #textarea').text(text);
    } else {};
};
```

I am using the [Clipboard.getContent()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.clipboard#Windows_ApplicationModel_DataTransfer_Clipboard_GetContent) and the [DataPackageView.getTextAsync(Windows.System.String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datapackageview#Windows_ApplicationModel_DataTransfer_DataPackageView_GetTextAsync_System_String_) Methods.

The interesting thing is that it does not matter how much text I copy to the clipboard, it will always say that `content.contains(Windows.System.string)` equals `false` and will show an exception for `content.getTextAsync(Windows.System.string);`

This is the exception:

> 0x8004006a - JavaScript runtime error: Invalid clipboard format
>   DataPackage does not contain the specified format. Verify its presence using DataPackageView.Contains or DataPackageView.AvailableFormats.
>   WinRT information: DataPackage does not contain the specified format. Verify its presence using DataPackageView.Contains or DataPackageView.AvailableFormats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Windows.System.string as paramter is wrong try content.contains(Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.StandardDataFormats.text)

Comment: You were right. At least the DataPckageView passes the if statement. But the object that `JSON.stringify(content.getTextAsync(Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.StandardDataFormats.text))` returns is `{"operation":{}}`. That doesn't make sense...

Comment: GetTextAsync is async and returns a JavaScript promise rather than the actual text. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/threading-async/asynchronous-programming-universal-windows-platform-apps#asynchronous-patterns-in-uwp-using-javascript for how to execute it.